# x.equals(x) and x.equals(null)

Tags: java, equals

Let's assume we have this example code:

```java
Fish fish;

fish.equals(null);
fish.equals(fish);
```

The equals method has not been overwritten and the fish variable has not been initialized which means, that java will nullify it?

So would both line return `true`?
And why would that be so? Would it also be possible to use an class variable when the object is not initialized?

Comment: Why don't you try and let us know

Comment: Have you read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object) ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question doesn't show any effors made.

Comment: Do you understand what is meant by `null`?

Answer (score 8):

If `fish` is a local variable, this code won't pass compilation, since `fish` must be initialized.

If `fish` is an instance variable, this code will throw NullPointerException, since the default value of `fish` will be null, and de-referencing a null reference throws this exception.

Answer (score 2):

After the statement `Fish fish;`, `fish` will be `null`; i.e. it is not referring to an object.

You'll get null pointer exception when executing `fish.equals(null);` since `fish` is itself `null`, so `equals` will not be available.

Comment: So if an object was not initialized it is acctually null?!

Comment: There's no *object* here: `fish` is not *referring* to anything.